# Why doesn't this Kronecker Product work with columns, but with rows?

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra, tensors

Using the formula given in [this math.stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048304/how-to-rewrite-m-1-otimes-m-2-isolating-m-2) by the user greg

$$\eqalign{
vec(M\otimes dK) &= \left(\pmatrix{I_T\otimes (M \cdot e_1)\cr I_T\otimes (M \cdot e_2)\cr \vdots \cr I_T \otimes (M \cdot e_T)}\otimes I_T\right) \cdot vec(dK)\cr
}$$

how come when I run the following code, I get `False`?

```
T = 5;
dim = 3;

dKmat = Array[dKm, {T, T}];
M1mat = Array[M1m, {dim, dim}];
Kron3 = KroneckerProduct[M1mat, dKmat];

ArrayReshape[Kron3, {Times @@ Dimensions[Kron3], 1}] === 
 KroneckerProduct[
   Flatten[Table[
     KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[T, SparseArray], 
      Transpose[{M1mat[[;; , i]]}]], {i, dim}], 1], 
   IdentityMatrix[T, SparseArray]].ArrayReshape[
   dKmat, {Times @@ Dimensions[dKmat], 1}]
```

However, if instead of the columns of `M1mat` in `M1mat[[;; , i]]`, I use the rows of `M1mat`, as `M1mat[[i]]`, then I get True...

Using the rows instead of the columns doesn't make mathematical sense to me. How is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use the "wrong" $vec$: Usually *columns* of a matrix are stacked by $vec$, not rows. You effectively use

```
vec[x_?MatrixQ] := Flatten[x];
```

but you *should* use

```
vec[x_?MatrixQ] := Flatten[Transpose[x]];
```

Now,

```
id = IdentityMatrix[T, SparseArray];
LHS = vec[KroneckerProduct[M1mat, dKmat]];
RHS = Dot[
   KroneckerProduct[
    Flatten[
     Table[
      KroneckerProduct[
       id,
       M1mat[[;; , {i}]]
       ],
      {i, dim}],
     1
     ],
    id
    ],
   vec[dKmat]
   ];
LHS == RHS
```

> True

Comment: yes, my mistake. Many thanks Henrik. ;)

Comment: No problem, You're always welcome.